# Magento 1.9.2 - Display any single address of a customer in account dashboard (frontend)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-address

I would display any single address of a customer and show it on account dashboard for a my work. How can i do?

I tried with this:

```
echo Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getAddress(2);

echo Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCustomer()->getAddress(1);
```

Any of this code works...

Answer (score 0):

If you have customer Id, then use below code to get the address of the corresponding customer.

```
$customerId = /* Required Customer ID */;
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId); // insert customer ID

$addresses = array()

foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address)
{
    $addresses[] = $address->toArray();
}
```

Now you may access the addresses as `$addresses[0]`, `$addresses[1]` ....

Alternatively, if you are looking for a specific type of address, then use any of the below methods.

```
$customerId = /* Required Customer ID */;
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId); // insert customer ID

$primaryBillingAddress = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress(); /* Primary Billing Address */
$primaryShippingAddress = $customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress(); /* Primary Shipping Address */

$defaultBillingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress(); /* Default Billing Address */

$defaultShippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress(); /* Default Shipping Address */
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i would like to recall the customer's address without specifying with the php which is the shipping or billing address. I would like to recall and display text it like this ->getAddress (1) or ->getAddress (2)

Comment: I have updated my answer now. Look at the first part of the answer. You  may access the addresses now as $addresses[0], $addresses[1]